# Using Count with multiple filters from different tables

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, countif, selectedvalue

I'm fairly new to Powerbi. I'm trying to count something using Filters from different tables and an 'OR' operator currently to no avail.

Tables are joined currently on a Many to One relationship. Table 1 being 'Many' and table 2 being 'One'.

Wondering if any one can help?

Retained =

```
     IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table2'[Excluded Indicator]) = 0 &&
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[Mid-Term Cancellation Indicator]) = 0 &&
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table2'[Lapsed Indicator]) = 0 &&
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[Renewal Cancellation Indicator]) = 0 &&
    
       (SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[Renewed Indicator]) = 1
     || SELECTEDVALUE('Table2'[Renewed Indicator]) = 1))

    ,count('Table1'[Membership]),0)
```

I want to count the memberships where the top 4 criteria are true and either one of the bottom two are.

When I put the above measure against a membership number it correctly shows the status, however, when aggregating against other columns it shows no values..

Comment: Post some sample rows from your tables, how the tables relate, and what your expected result would be.